# big number for id with insert into statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am developing an application in Access using vba. I wan't to insert a temporary table in another table called "Reports". The table Reports has an id with auto increment. Now my temporary table hasnt got an id. So I thought Access would automatically change the ID of Reports following the last ID. (so a new row would get ID = 2 when the last ID = 1). But when I run my insert into statement Access generates an ID over 5500000, not followed with my previous record. Does anyone knows what causes this problem?

```
strSql = "INSERT INTO Reports SELECT * FROM tblTemp;"
CurrentDb.Execute strSql
```

Thx for the help

Edit: just found out that he does it too when I just add a record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List the names of the fields in `Reports` which will receive data.  Omit the `ID` field from that list, and let the db engine supply the autonumber value.

For example, if `Reports` includes fields: `ID`; `fld2`; and `fld3` ...

```
INSERT INTO [Reports] (fld2, fld3) SELECT fldA, fldB FROM tblTemp;
```

Notes:

1. `Reports` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#R), so I bracketed that name to avoid confusing the db engine.
2. If you care about the autonumber seed value and it's presently at 5500000 even after deleting all the `Reports` rows, compact the database to reset the seed value to one larger than the greatest stored `ID` value.

Comment: I found it. I got my data from an excel import, were I didnt define the ID cause I thought access do that automatically. Access does it but when u add a new record afterwards it will give u an ID over 500000. Still don't know why, but my problem is solved. But thanks anyway